# ¿Como agregar iconos a los archivos JS y CSS en las urls?

Tags: .htaccess

He visto que algunas paginas tienen el favicon de la pagina en las urls, de los archivos JS y CSS.

Me gustaría saber como lograrlo.

Se que es una pregunta algo extraña o loca, o como deseen verlo, pero quisiera saber como hacerlo con htaccess.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Podrías señalar un ejemplo?

Comment: Por ejemplo el script js de facebook osea este https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=801240033310541 tiene el favicon de facebook. Como logran hacer eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca el archivo con tu icono en la el directorio raíz de tu sitio, con la peculiaridad que debe llamarse `favicon.ico` y debe tener el formato `ico`. Este archivo es solicitado automáticamente por los navegadores y lo aplica a **todos los archivos** del dominio.

Si deseas usar una imagen con otro formato **a tus páginas** puedes usar la siguiente meta etiqueta:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/mi_image.png">
```

Y se recomienda que la imagen sea pequeña y cuadrada. Las dimensiones más comunes son 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 px.

Puedes usar convertidores en línea para crear un `favicon` a partir de una image. Algunos sitios donde puedes hacerlo son los siguientes:

- https://iconverticons.com/online/
- http://imagen.online-convert.com/es/convertir-a-ico
- http://convertico.com/

Comment: Vaya jajajaja, yo siempre lo he guardado en una subcarpeta. xD esperomos funcione. Gracias. :)

Comment: Si funciono amigo, muchas gracias. :)